# Fastest way to get collection of products by attribute

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

i have a store that i have a lot of products, more than 50,000 products, and trying to figure out one of the issues with the pageload of my home page, one of them i already found it (frontend) but now im checking on the backend, for example i have different blocks of products like (featured, latest products and products by category), so since i only load like 8 products (each block) in my store home page maybe 50,000 (and it keeps groing) makes it slower i think, so maybe i can improve the performance on my code.

The Method im using to call the products are featured:

```
$_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        $_products->addAttributeToSelect("*");
        $_products->addFieldToFilter(
            array(
            array('attribute'=>'featured', 'eq'=> 1)     
        )
        );
```

Is there a way to make it faster? Or maybe the issue is also in the latest products or filtering the products by category?

Answer (score 0):

This code already creates optimal query. Try to reduce the number of selected fields when using addAttributeToSelect. Also consider usage of flat tables to gain more performance. (works on >100k catalogs). Profiler tools like newrelic may give you more info about specific performance bottlenecks of your code.

Comment: O already activate Flat catalog on admin. Ir do i need yo change elsething more?

Comment: If you just activated product flat, then you will have to run product flat index to create flat tables.

Comment: But how do i run product flat index to create the flat tables?

Comment: In Magento admin under System->Index Management click on "Reindex Data" for entry "Product Flat Data". Or if it fails you can do it in command line under /shell with "php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_flat"

Answer (score 0):

In addition to samsonovits answer, I would also suggest clearing out your log tables. See here: https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-perform-magento-database-maintenance.html.